# Uploading custom Javascript via cPanel - Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, cpanel

Forgive my lack of knowledge - I am looking for the correct directory to add a JS script using a cPanel. I want the script to be triggered immediately as users access the webpage (not sure if that matters or not).

So far I have found outdated answers on Youtube and bits of information from Stack Overflow but no definitive answers.

Any guidance/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

try this

upload you Js in `root\js` folder. And call this code in your head.phtml file at top.

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS)."/yourjs.js"; ?>
```

Comment: I used the HTML header function on Magento's front end as a solution. When I need to add more scripts, I will try this approach. Thank you for the help.